# SharePoint Error Code 65545

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am converting word file to docx. It is working file  But if I am uploading large file greater than 50 MB than it is not converting. I have check in word automation database it shows error no 65545. I have try with 8-10 different word file.

Answer (score 1):

I can't guarantee that this is the answer, but 50 MB is the default maximum allowed file upload size for a web application in SP 2010.

This is configurable though; the farm administrator can change this value in Central Administration.

In 2010 and 2013: Central Administration > Manage Web Applications (under Application Management) > Select the Web Application > General Settings (in the ribbon) > General Settings (in the dropdown)

See [Plan for caching and performance (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424404%28office.14%29.aspx#Section3) for 2010 or [Plan for caching and performance in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424404%28v=office.15%29.aspx#Section3) for 2013 (though this area of the article is effectively unchanged version to version).